# How to use only one for loop to find the grids in two 2d arrays that have the same value in the same position?

Tags: for-loop

Given two 3*3 squares, each grid inside the square has a value in it. How to find the same value in the two grids that in the same position?
e.g.
Square A:
1 3 5
4 9 8
2 6 7

Square B:
3 4 7
1 9 8
2 5 6

The function should return 9, 8, 2

Constraint: You're allowed to use only one for loop.

My thought:
The most naive thought would be to have two for loops to compare each square, that would be easy, but the constraint is that I'm allowed to use only one for loop?
Then I was thinking to convert each square into a 1d array in order, and then just compare the two converted 1d arrays, but looks like we still need a nested for loop to do the conversion.

So, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I think it is supposed to look for the same values in both squares (at the same position)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the best approach is depends from the language... The language independent will be like: 

    for (i from 0 to rows * columns) {
         row = i / columns;
         col = i % columns;
         if (a[row][col] == b[row][col]) -> yield_result;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C & C++ you can easily do it in one for loop as

```
int arr[3][3];
```

will be stored as contiguous memory block.

so you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    if (*arr1 == *arr2) cout << *arr1;
    ++arr1;
    ++arr2;
}
```

in other languages you can use some tricks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    if (arr1[i/3][i%3] == arr2[i/3][i%3]) { /* print result */ };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say `i` is your loop variable. Then you can access the column with

```
i / array.length
```

and the line with

```
i % array.length
```

Maybe this java loop makes it clearer:

```
int[][] array = {{1,3,5},{4,9,8},{2,6,7}};    

for(int i = 0; i < array.length * array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i / array.length][i % array.length]);
}
```

Your `i` obviously has to run till `length * length`

This loop outputs the matching results of two arrays `a1` and `a2`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a1.length * a1.length; i++){
    int a1Content = a1[i / a1.length][i % a1.length];
    int a2Content = a2[i / a2.length][i % a2.length];

    if(a1Content == a2Content){
        System.out.println(a1Content);
    }
}
```